# Can an observer watch billions of years of history in a few hours?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers

Say a spaceship leaves Earth today, travels for x years at 0.9999999c, and then decelerates and stops (back to Earth's frame of reference, but far away). Almost everything else in the universe will now be much older.

If deceleration is not discrete, but continuous, it means in y hours of deceleration, potentially millions of years of space history would be observed by the spaceship. Is this correct? What am I missing?

Comment: Please edit the post to be a single, cohesive post. Don't keep old content in the post; there is an edit history available for those who want to look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not only during the deceleration time that one ship sees the other in 'fast forward mode'. Because they are approaching, it happens during all the journey.

What happens during the deceleration time is that this mode gradually turns to 'play'.

In case 1, it happens equally for both.

In case 2, it is possible that STATIC sees FAST even at slow motion during that time, in spite of being approaching, if the deceleration is big enough.

Comment: Before deceleration, when both are approaching each other, do they see the other in 'fast forward mode', or slow motion? I believe it's slow motion (the clocks in the other spaceship seem to move slower because it's moving very fast relative to the observer). So then the fast forward mode starts only when deceleration starts, right?

Comment: There are 2 competing issues. On one hand, the other time flows slowly due relativity. On the other hand, the same principle of the Doppler effect applies. The time interval of events inside one ship is smaller, when perceived by the other ship. Note that if they were receding, the recording of events would be ultra slow motion because in this case both effects would add.

Comment: Thanks, Claudio. So in case 2, if the spaceships cameras corrected for Doppler effect (assume they know their planned trajectories and speeds), then is it true that in y minutes of deceleration, z years of STATIC's history can be observed by FAST (and z depends on how long they were traveling before meeting, ie x)?

Comment: This site(https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html) shows a table that relates T(time for FAST) and t(time for STATIC) for a comfortable deceleration of 1 g until rest. The relation depends only on the initial relative speed. The time before braking is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks, Claudio, that is a super interesting resource! I'm still curious, final question: say a spaceship leaves Earth today, travels for x years at 0.9999999c, and then decelerates and stops (back to Earth's frame of reference, but far away). Everything else in the universe will now be much older (right?). If deceleration is not discrete, but continuous, it means in y minutes of deceleration, potentially millions of years of space history would be observed by the spaceship. Is this correct?

Comment: @BrunoFiss I suggest that you post this comment as another question. The site is not designed for long threads of comments.

Comment: Thanks! Posted here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742995/how-much-of-earths-history-can-a-spaceship-traveling-at-near-speed-of-light-rec

Answer (score 2):

Judging by your comment on Claudio's answer, you have understood everything the wrong way around. When two ships are approaching each other, each will 'see' time on the other speeded up, owing to the Doppler effect. (I put the word 'see' in quotes because in reality you would never see anything in the everyday sense of the word if you were moving at close to the speed of light.) As the relative speed of the spaceships decreases, the magnitude of the Doppler effect will reduce, so that when the two ships are stationary relative to each other they will eventually see time on the other running at a normal rate.

I have included the word 'eventually' for an important reason, which is that if one ship decelerates, they will immediately see a reduction in the Doppler effect that applies to light coming from the other ship, but there will be a time lag before the other ship will see the same reduction in relation to the light it receives.

Comment: Thanks, Marco! I totally ignored Doppler, I'm so sorry, thanks for clarifying. Let me try to reframe the question: say a spaceship leaves Earth today, travels for x years at 99.99999% of the speed of light, and then decelerates and stops (back to Earth's frame of reference, but far away). Everything else in the universe will now be much older (right?). If deceleration is not discrete, but continuous, it means in y minutes of deceleration, potentially millions of years of space history would be observed by the spaceship. Is this correct?

Comment: I have never heard of the effects of time dilation bring called the Doppler effect. Certainly they are related, but aren't they still separate things? Or do you mean one is using a clock that specifically looks at the frequency of incoming light rays?

Comment: @BrunoFiss no that's not right. In y minutes of deceleration you would see less than y minutes of history if you were moving away from the Earth.

Comment: @BioPhysicist time dilation and the Doppler effect are separate but inter-related effects. The Doppler effect is important when you need to account for the appearance of a light source moving relative to you.

Comment: @Marco Ocram appreciate it. Still struggling a bit. Let me try a final reframing: let's say the spaceship continuously travels around the earth in a triangle. When it's going straight, it should see Earth's denizens moving more slowly. When it turns at one of the corners of the triangle, "suddenly" Earth moves a bit forward in time. I believe this move should be continuous, not discrete, meaning a bunch of observable things would happen on Earth in a short amount of time (during the turn). So in this case would the spaceship be able to observe a lot of Earth's future history during each turn?

Comment: @BrunoFiss The Earth never jumps forward in spacetime. The Earth's time coordinate in the frame of reference of the spaceship changes abruptly when the spaceship accelerates or decelerates some distance away. For example, today might have a time coordinate of, say, 28th December 2013 in the frame of some spaceship far away, and an acceleration by the spaceship might change the coordinate of today to being  28th December 2033 in the spaceship's new frame. Here today is 28th December 2023. The only thing that is changing is the coordinate used to label today....

Comment: ...we don't all suddenly leap forward to 2033 because a spaceship far away has accelerated.

Comment: Thanks for all the patience, Marco. I still have additional questions, so I made this into a separate question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/742995/how-much-of-earths-history-can-a-spaceship-traveling-at-near-speed-of-light-rec
I hope this doesn't come across wrong, and I'm not confident this is the right place for this kind of question. I'll happily delete either one of them or both if they are not productive for the community. Again, appreciate the help.